# How to do refactoring "extract function" in Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, eclipse, aptana

I'm Java/jQuery developer. is there any "extract function" refactoring for JavaScript in Eclipse or Aptana or any other JavaScript/jQuery IDE?

Comment: You've tagged your question both `java` and `javascript`, and you've put "in Javascript" in your title. Java and JavaScript are very different languages, are you after an answer for both? Or is the `java` tag incorrect?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want answer in both. Java and Javascript.

Comment: Then I recommend editing your question. It says "JavaScript" and "jQuery" (which is a JavaScript library) all over the place, the only place Java is really mentioned is in the tags. Very easy to miss that you're looking for refactoring in both languages. (A lot of people say "Java" when they mean "JavaScript", so a lot of us reading the question will read right past it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely agree. Eclipse is a fantastic ebvironment for Java, but for javascript it's a real nightmare. If you really want a free IDE then I would recommend Netbeans (7.1) above Eclipse. Its jabascript support is so much better. Try to define javascript 'classes' and you will find out why Eclipse is not up to the job (Helio). I'm terribly disappointed.

I have given Webstorm a try too, and it is indeed a very good (certainly better than Eclipse and Netbeans) development environment, but it takes time to get used to it. I can imagine that developers don't like switching to Webstorm because they, like me, are so used to Eclipse. But I think we just need to be patient... and we will be greatly rewarded ;-).

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, both [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and its big brother [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) both do.

For Java, IntelliJ IDEA does, and I believe [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) has an extensive set of refactorings (including "extract function") for Java. I'd be surprised if [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) doesn't as well.

Comment: @IAdapter: Eclipse and Netbeans are both free, but if you want really top-notch JavaScript support, I recommend evaluating WebStorm and/or IDEA and comparing their JavaScript support to Eclipse and Netbeans. For me, it's a no-brainer, I'm happy to pay the small amount necessary.

Comment: i prefer "learn once, use everywhere" and that is only for free products. but i will try this WebStorm.